# Changing HTTP User-Agent field in RestKit

Tags: iphone, ios, http, restkit

The server that my app is connecting to only responds to certain user-agent values. I'm using `NSURLConnection` right now, which can do this. However, I'm thinking about switching to `RestKit` to simplify my code base.

Is there a way to change the HTTP User-Agent field in RestKit? Will [additionalHTTPHeaders](http://restkit.org/api/0.9/Classes/RKRequest.html#//api/name/additionalHTTPHeaders) overwrite the default one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be changed at the [RKClient](http://restkit.org/api/0.10.3/Classes/RKClient.html). The `-setValue:forHTTPHeaderField:` method can be used to overwrite the default User-Agent header.

I just tested this and confirmed that it works.